# rendering symfony/form in non-symfony application

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

I'm trying to rewrite a "custom framework" application to the Symfony, but I can not do everything at once, so I've divided the process into steps.

From important notes - I've already implemented the `symfony/templating` component and the `symfony/twig-bridge` component.

That's how I want to output the form in the template:

```
<?php echo $view['form']->form($form) ?>
```

As I'm doing so the following error is thrown:

```
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\LogicException
No block "form" found while rendering the form.
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/form/FormRenderer.php on line 98
```

To render the templates I'm using the `DelegatingEngine` which uses the `PhpEngine` and the `TwigEngine`.

Setting up the Twig with the `\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension` is [well documented](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#twig-templating), but what I'm missing is the php setup. This is how I'm doing this:

```
new \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Templating\TemplatingExtension($phpEngine, $this->csrfManager());
```

Could you point me what am I missing or what's wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer:

I was using the wrong `FormRendererEngineInterface`. Instead of relying on the `\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Templating\TemplatingExtension` class I've registered the `form` helper by myself:

```
$phpEngine = new PhpEngine(new TemplateNameParser(), new FilesystemLoader(realpath(__DIR__.'/../Template').'/%name%'));
$twigEngine = new TwigEngine($this->twig(), new TemplateNameParser());

$this->TemplateEngine = new DelegatingEngine(array(
    $phpEngine,
    $twigEngine,
));

$phpEngine->addHelpers(array(
    new FormHelper(new FormRenderer($this->twigFormRendererEngine())),
));
```

As you can see in the TemplatingEngine:

```
public function __construct(PhpEngine $engine, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager = null, array $defaultThemes = array())
    {
        $engine->addHelpers(array(
            new FormHelper(new FormRenderer(new TemplatingRendererEngine($engine, $defaultThemes), $csrfTokenManager)),
        ));
    }
```

It relies on the `TemplatingRendererEngine` while I need the `TwigRendererEngine` instance, as the form templates are the twig files.

Correct me if my explanation is wrong, but the solution is working.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way would have been to install the Symfony 3.3 standard edition next to your app (pending the release of Symfony Flex).

After this, find a way to use the router of Symfony with the router of your application.

So you could have the full Symfony framework, create your form type in it and let Symfony render it :

1. With an ajax call
2. With a new [Symfony Kernel](http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/micro_kernel_trait.html) in your legacy app

Comment: that's a nice idea but it'd involve a mess in the project :/

Comment: it also doesn't answer the question. I'll try and look at your proposed solution as I am stuck on this pohole in my freedom's adventure into creating Symfony Forms within Standalone context. I'll report back on this, interesting read.

Comment: @roomcayz Also I'd suggest updating the answer with namespace references at least. I think it could be much more useful to know where your dependencies come from.